# How to mirror a WiX dialog for right-to-left languages?

Tags: wix, right-to-left

WiX `Dialog` element and `Control` element have `RightAligned` and `RightToLeft` attributes. But setting this bits to 'yes' doesn't seem to cause a dialog mirrored. (I'm using custom dialogs, not WiX provided ones.) Should I calculate manually mirrored location of every control and edit `X` coordinate of them?